# (Pyrebase) error : orderBy must be a valid JSON encoded path

Tags: python, json, firebase, nosql, pyrebase

I use firebase and my JSON(Firebase) is as below.
I want to retrieve the key values(**288xxx**) by using **busStopName** values.

[image]

My code is as below. I'll make an example with '**윤정사앞**'

```
# Retriving id by using value
def getIdByName(db, name) :
    bus = db.child("busStops").order_by_child("busStopName").equal_to(name).get()
    print(bus.key())
...

...
getIdByName(db, "윤정사앞")
```

My ideal result of this code was **288000001**.
But there are errors, which are '**Bad Request**' and '**orderBy must be a valid JSON encoded path**'.

Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

You have to go into rules in firebase, and update rules that you can do it.
In rules, in firebase, you need to update this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": ...
    ".write": ...
      "busStops": {
         ".indexOn": "busStopName"
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this is for performance, and not required. The issue might be this: https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase/issues/296

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with Pyrebase, I found this solution on Github, all you need to do is uninstall 'pyrebase' and then install pyrebase4 like so:

```
pip uninstall pyrebase
pip install pyrebase4
```